# What's the best way to exclude routes from a sitemap using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Getting a list of all routes to use in building sitemaps is simple, *e.g.,* `rules = current_app.url_map.iter_rules()`. But a number of routes in my app are intended for administrative functions and these should be excluded from sitemaps (both XML and human-readable). All such administrative routes have a decorator `@auth_role(...)` (shown below, and which is very similar to the `@login_required` decorator described in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/). URLs do not have a special segment that sets them apart from other non-administrative URLs. So I'd like to be able to filter routes to exclude those pointing to view functions that also have the `@auth_role(...)` decorator. Does it make sense to do it this way? If so, how can this be done? If not, should I revise all administrative routes to include some segment that sets them apart from routes for public consumption?

```
def auth_role(roles):
    def _auth_role_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                if g.user is None:
                    flash(u'You must login to access the requested resource.', CSS.ERR)
                    path = urlsplit(request.url).path
                    if path in ['', '/', '/admin']:
                        return redirect('/admin/login')
                    else:
                        return redirect('/admin/login?d=%s' % path)
                if not g.user.is_active():
                    flash(u'Your account is no longer active.', CSS.ERR)
                    return abort(403)
                if not g.user.is_authorized(roles):
                    flash(u'Your current role does not grant access to this resource.', CSS.ERR)
                    return abort(403)
            except KeyError:
                return abort(401)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return _inner
    return _auth_role_required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your decorator to also register the target function in a "not mapped" list. You can then subtract that list from the big list of routes.

For example:

```
def auth_role(roles):
    def _auth_role_required(f):
        @wraps(f)

        # add to not_mapped list
        register_not_mapped(f.__name__)

        def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
            # ...
        return _inner
    return _auth_role_required
```

Comment: Miguel. This is interesting. I will give it a try and see how it works. Thanks.